# I have some trouble with golang syscall when calling dll in win7-64

Tags: go, system-calls

Here my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

var (
    WinSCard, _                  = syscall.LoadLibrary("C:\\windows\\system32\\WinSCard.dll")
    procSCardListReaders, _      = syscall.GetProcAddress(WinSCard, "SCardListReaders")
    procSCardEstablishContext, _ = syscall.GetProcAddress(WinSCard, "SCardEstablishContext")
)

func abort(funcname string, err error) {
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("%s failed: %v", funcname, err))
}

func SCardEstablishContext(dwScope uint32, pvReserved1 *uint32, pvReserved2 *uint32, phContext uintptr) int32 {
    ret, _, callErr := syscall.Syscall6(uintptr(procSCardEstablishContext),
        4,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&dwScope)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pvReserved1)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pvReserved2)),
        phContext,
        0,
        0)
    if callErr != 0 {
        abort("Err:", callErr)
    }
    return int32(ret)
}

func main() {
    var Hwd uintptr
    defer syscall.FreeLibrary(WinSCard)
    rt := SCardEstablishContext(0, nil, nil, Hwd)
    fmt.Println(rt)
}
```

Return -2146435068 means 0x80100004 means SCARD_E_INVALID_PARAMETER. One or more of the supplied parameters could not be properly interpreted.

The func SCardEstablishContext:

```
LONG WINAPI SCardEstablishContext(
    _In_   DWORD dwScope,
    _In_   LPCVOID pvReserved1,
    _In_   LPCVOID pvReserved2,
    _Out_  LPSCARDCONTEXT phContext
)
```

What's wrong with my parameters? Thx a lot!!

How about

```
func SCardListReaders(hContext *syscall.Handle, mszGroups string, mszReaders *byte, pcchReaders *uint32) (err error) {
r1, _, e1 := syscall.Syscall6(
    uintptr(procSCardListReaders),
    4,
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(hContext)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringBytePtr(mszGroups))),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(mszReaders)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pcchReaders)),
    0,
    0,
)
if r1 != 0 {
    if e1 != 0 {
        err = error(e1)
    } else {
        err = syscall.EINVAL
    }
}
return
}

var Groups string
var Readers byte
var pcchReaders uint32
er1 := SCardListReaders(&context, Groups, &Readers, &pcchReaders)
if er1 != nil {
    fmt.Println("SCardListReaders:", er1)
    return
}
```

return: invalid argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unicode/utf16"
    "unsafe"
)

var (
    WinSCard, _                  = syscall.LoadLibrary(`C:\windows\system32\WinSCard.dll`)
    procSCardEstablishContext, _ = syscall.GetProcAddress(WinSCard, "SCardEstablishContext")
    procSCardReleaseContext, _   = syscall.GetProcAddress(WinSCard, "SCardReleaseContext")
    procSCardListReaders, _      = syscall.GetProcAddress(WinSCard, "SCardListReadersW")
)

const (
    SCARD_SCOPE_USER   = 0
    SCARD_SCOPE_SYSTEM = 2

    SCARD_ALL_READERS     = "SCard$AllReaders"
    SCARD_DEFAULT_READERS = "SCard$DefaultReaders"
)

func SCardListReaders(hContext syscall.Handle, mszGroups *uint16, mszReaders *uint16, pcchReaders *uint32) (retval error) {
    r0, _, _ := syscall.Syscall6(
        uintptr(procSCardListReaders),
        4,
        uintptr(hContext),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(mszGroups)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(mszReaders)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pcchReaders)),
        0,
        0,
    )
    if r0 != 0 {
        retval = syscall.Errno(r0)
    }
    return
}

func SCardReleaseContext(hContext syscall.Handle) (retval error) {
    r0, _, _ := syscall.Syscall(
        uintptr(procSCardReleaseContext),
        1,
        uintptr(hContext),
        0,
        0,
    )
    if r0 != 0 {
        retval = syscall.Errno(r0)
    }
    return
}

func SCardEstablishContext(dwScope uint32, pvReserved1 uintptr, pvReserved2 uintptr, phContext *syscall.Handle) (retval error) {
    r0, _, _ := syscall.Syscall6(
        uintptr(procSCardEstablishContext),
        4,
        uintptr(dwScope),
        uintptr(pvReserved1),
        uintptr(pvReserved2),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(phContext)),
        0,
        0,
    )
    if r0 != 0 {
        retval = syscall.Errno(r0)
    }
    return
}

func ReturnValue(err error) uint32 {
    rv, ok := err.(syscall.Errno)
    if !ok {
        rv = 0
    }
    return uint32(rv)
}

func UTF16ToStrings(ls []uint16) []string {
    var ss []string
    if len(ls) == 0 {
        return ss
    }
    if ls[len(ls)-1] != 0 {
        ls = append(ls, 0)
    }
    i := 0
    for j, cu := range ls {
        if cu == 0 {
            if j >= 1 && ls[j-1] == 0 {
                break
            }
            if j-i > 0 {
                ss = append(ss, string(utf16.Decode(ls[i:j])))
            }
            i = j + 1
            continue
        }
    }
    return ss
}

func main() {
    var (
        context  syscall.Handle
        scope    uint32
        groups   *uint16
        cReaders uint32
    )

    context = 0
    groups, err := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(SCARD_ALL_READERS)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Reader Group: ", err)
        return
    }
    err = SCardListReaders(context, groups, nil, &cReaders)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("SCardListReaders: 0x%X %s\n", ReturnValue(err), err)
        return
    }
    r := make([]uint16, cReaders)
    err = SCardListReaders(context, groups, &r[0], &cReaders)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("SCardListReaders: 0x%X %s\n", ReturnValue(err), err)
        return
    }
    readers := UTF16ToStrings(r[:cReaders])
    fmt.Println("Readers:", len(readers), readers)

    scope = SCARD_SCOPE_SYSTEM
    err = SCardEstablishContext(scope, 0, 0, &context)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("SCardEstablishContext: 0x%X %s\n", ReturnValue(err), err)
        return
    }
    defer SCardReleaseContext(context)
    fmt.Printf("Context: %X\n", context)
}
```

Output:

Computer 1:

```
Readers: 1 [O2 O2Micro CCID SC Reader 0]
Context: CD00000100000000
```

Computer 2:

```
Readers: 0 []
SCardEstablishContext: 0x8010001D The Smart card resource manager is not running.
```

Also, note the fix for the `procSCardListReaders` `ProcName`:

```
procSCardListReaders, _ = syscall.GetProcAddress(WinSCard, "SCardListReadersW")
```

Comment: I've revised my answer to answer the second question, and I also made improvements to my answer to the first question. The error handling is much improved. You can now get the return value as well as the formatted message text. I nearly missed your revised question because the question had already been answered and accepted. Next time, post a new question so that it's easy to see.

Comment: I have revised my answer to further simplify the code for `syscall` return values.

Comment: This helped me get a syscall for openCL working on my window's machine. Which I did because the CUDA TOOLKIT for windows does not give you .a files to link against. And CGO uses mingw.

Don't understand why ignoring the 3rd output from syscall9 works though. Why would it contain an error code #203, but still work?